# How update the vue template at the run-time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am working on the CMS based vue page. In the page I have one root container inside that I have two child container as looks below

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="above-the-fold">...</div>
    <div class="below-the-fold noscript-container">
        <noscript>
            <div v-if="true">{{someDynamicBinding}}</div>
            <div v-if="false">{{someDynamicBinding}}</div>
        </noscript>
    </div>
</div>
```

If javascript is enabled I am removing noscript tag and appending inside contents to the parent element using a below script.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const appendContents = function () {
    const noScript = document.querySelector(".noscriptcontainer noscript");
    const belowContent = noScript.innerHTML;
    noScript.parentElement.innerHTML += belowContent;
    console.log("elm appended");
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", appendContents);
    noScript.remove();
    console.log("eve removed");
  };
  window.addEventListener("scroll", appendContents);
});
```

Now the problem is vue doesn't evaluating `v-if` or `{{dynamicBinding}}`
Jsfiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/69yr3mp5/2/

Now what is the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the second if with v-else-if

```
                <div v-if="true"><h1>
                        {{someDynamicBinding}}
                    </h1></div>
                    <div v-else-if="false"><h1>
                        {{someDynamicBinding}}
                    </h1></div>
                </noscript>
```

Comment: This is not make any sense. Still its not recompiling code inside below the fold container

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR;

You can update the template run-time, but **you can't update the template after component is mounted**.

---

Run-time, in the context of these frameworks, means that it is not pre-compiled, which is something that Vue supports. However, the problem here (one of them anyway) is that you are modifying the template after the application is mounted. The Vue app will not continue to check the template after the initial read. While I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, It seems that the approach is wrong.

To illustrate, if you use this code, it will compile the updated code, but not until you scroll.

```js
let mounted = false

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  const appendContents = function() {
    const noScript = document.querySelector(".noscript-container noscript");
    const belowContent = noScript.innerHTML;
    noScript.parentElement.innerHTML += belowContent;
    console.log("elm appended");
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", appendContents);
    noScript.remove();
    console.log("eve removed");

    if (!mounted) {
      Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            someDynamicBinding: 'Some Content'
          };
        },
        mounted() {
          console.log('mounted')
        },
      }).mount('#app');
    };
    mounted = true
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", appendContents);
});
```

Comment: Here I don't want to show below the fold contents until user interact on the page. contents inside the noscript tag will not render the contents at pageload. So It will increase our page load speed. That's why we are trying this approach.

Comment: That's not the way to do it though. Look into code splitting, here is an article that describes it in more detail https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-and-code-splitting-in-vue-js/